# Setting up the GTK4.0 library with CMake

Tags: c, cmake, compilation, gtk, libraries

I've been trying to set up GTK4.0 on my C project but I haven't found anything that works yet, besides maybe brutaly including every directory in the gtk version I've installed but I understandably want to have a more elegant solution.

Sorry if the problem is simple, I really need to get this done... Here's the current CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(ProjectCESGI C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Wall")

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK REQUIRED gtk-4.0)

include_directories(${GTK4_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK4_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_definitions(${GTK4_CFLAGS_OTHER})

target_link_libraries(gtk_test ${GTK4_LIBRARIES})

link_directories(C:/gtk-build/gtk/x64/release/lib)
link_libraries(gtk)
add_executable(ProjectCESGI main.c)
target_link_libraries(ProjectCESGI gtk)
```

If you need something else let me know.

I tried to brute-force my way out of the not found headers, but stopped halfway through realising how ridiculous the process was.
I also tried to look for a package which should somehow help me install the library, PkgConfig, but this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample/minimal reproducer code and steps to reproduce the issue? Let me help you by trying it from my end

Comment: The first parameter passed to `pkg_check_modules` denotes the prefix for all variables created by that call. Since you pass `GTK` here, then the call will create variables like `GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS`. If you want to use `GTK4_INCLUDE_DIRS`, then instead pass `GTK4` as the first parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(ProjectCESGI LANGUAGES C)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK4 REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET gtk4)

add_executable(ProjectCESGI main.c)
target_link_libraries(ProjectCESGI PRIVATE PkgConfig::GTK4)
```

It's *always* better to use an imported target when one is available, and `pkg_check_modules` can create one for you with the `IMPORTED_TARGET` option. When you link to an imported target via `target_link_libraries`, CMake knows to set up the appropriate include directories, link directories, compile definitions, etc. to use the library.

Carefully consult [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html#command:pkg_check_modules) if your build has trouble finding GTK4. Your build really should not be any more complex than this.

Comment: It works! I can't thank you enough for this!
Although I did have to change "gtk-4.0" to just "gtk4", but it finally works as intended... Thank you again!

Comment: This is not working for me. What dependencies did you install?